# How to find all the "subchannels" available in a snap channel?

Tags: snap

I know that you can get the exact channel an application is being refreshed to with `snap info`, looking for the "tracking" section, as in:

```
$ snap info snap-store
name:    snap-store
summary: Snap Store is a graphical desktop application for discovering, installing and managing
  snaps on Linux.
publisher: Canonical✓
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/snap-store
contact:   https://bugs.launchpad.net/snap-store/
license:   unset
description: |
  Snap Store showcases featured and popular applications with useful descriptions, ratings, reviews
  and screenshots.
  
  
  Applications can be found either through browsing categories
  or by searching.
  
  
  Snap Store can also be used to switch channels, view and alter snap permissions and view and
  submit reviews and ratings.
  
  
  Snap Store is based on GNOME Software, optimized for the Snap experience.
commands:
  - snap-store
  - snap-store.ubuntu-software
  - snap-store.ubuntu-software-local-file
snap-id:      gjf3IPXoRiipCu9K0kVu52f0H56fIksg
tracking:     latest/stable/ubuntu-20.04
refresh-date: today at 19:05 CEST
channels:
  latest/stable:    3.31.1+git187.84b64e0b 2020-04-22 (415) 45MB -
  latest/candidate: 3.31.1+git189.991d1d1d 2020-08-09 (472) 45MB -
  latest/beta:      3.36.0-82-g80486d0     2020-09-11 (481) 53MB -
  latest/edge:      20200414.ac9047f       2020-04-14 (375) 50MB -
installed:          3.36.0-82-g80486d0                (481) 53MB -
[1]+  Done                    snap-store
```

But the channels list output by the same command does not contain all the actual channels: in the example above "latest/stable/ubuntu-20.04" is not in the list.

How can I get the complete list of channels associated to a snap?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual nomenclature and purpose is explained at https://snapcraft.io/docs/channels

- <Track> / <Risk-Level> / <Branch>

So in your example: `tracking:     latest/stable/ubuntu-20.04`

- Track = latest
- Risk-level = stable
- Branch = ubuntu-20.04

And here's what the documentation has to say on the subject of *branches*

> A branch is an optional finer subdivision of a channel for a published snap that allows for the creation of a short-lived sequences of snaps that can be pushed on demand by snap developers to help with fixes or temporary experimentation.
>
> Branch names convey their purpose, such as fix-for-bug123, but the name isn’t exposed in the normal way, such as with snap info. Instead, they can be tracked by anyone simply knowing the name.

So there's no documented way for a user to *list* branches, sorry. Branches are rather intended the other way around - to limit software pushes to certain testers or devices. In your case, somebody running 20.04 instead of, say, 16.04 which has a different Gnome stack and completely different package data.

---

Let's test that we can actually touch a branch. Let's try a `snap refresh` with a known branch name (succeeds) and with a bogus branch name (no-such-branch error):

```
$ sudo snap refresh --channel=stable/ubuntu-20.04 snap-store
snap "snap-store" has no updates available

$ sudo snap refresh --channel=stable/ubuntu-blah snap-store
error: requested a non-existing branch on latest/stable for snap "snap-store": ubuntu-blah
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response; I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and the "Ubuntu Software" (snap-store) is not working properly (categories doesn't show and other issues) and I'm a bit lost looking for a solution. In the case of snap-store, I've learned you have to refresh on the latest/stable/ubuntu-20.04 _branch_ for the ubuntu _skin_ to be installed.